# How to fix the problem of 'Object of type XXXXX is not registered inside GetIt' in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use get_it in order to create a singleton object to be used. I do not wish to use multiple objects of API which is connecting to Firebase. The singleton object is that of Api call for firebase.

I have used the following code

```
locator.registerLazySingleton<Api>(() => new Api('teams')) ;
```

while following code works

```
locator.registerLazySingleton<TeamViewModel>(() => new TeamViewModel()) ;
```

The structure of Api class is as follows:

```
class Api{
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;
  
  Api( this.path ) {
    ref = _db.collection(path);
  }

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getDataCollection() {
     return ref.getDocuments() ;
  }
}`
```

This is how I use the API singleton object:

```
Api _api = locator<Api>();
```

while the following code works fine:

```
Api _api = Api('team');
```

I get the following error in console:

> I/flutter ( 2313): The following _Exception was thrown building MultiProvider:
>
> I/flutter ( 2313): Exception: Object of type Api is not registered inside GetIt

I wish to know if this is even possible of using getit is not the right way to go about this.

Comment: I had similar problem, just check the order of register

Comment: This is a bit tricky, with each version there are some changes in creating the GetIt Instance. In your code I think you don't need the 'new' keyword at all.
locator.registerLazySingleton<TeamViewModel>(() =>TeamViewModel()) ;

Comment: I had the same error. I was able to fix it, by letting all my connected objects being lazy created instead of being created all at the beginning. It seems that there were some connections between the Apis, I wasn't able to see and therefore the compiler complaint when the api got created without the service also already being created

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I changed my register to lazy register in my case - fixed my problem;

Answer (score 24, accepted):

don't forget to call setupLocator in your main app file before App init

```
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
```

Comment: What is `setupLocator`? I don`t find references for it.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code on your main function.

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void main() {

  locator.registerLazySingleton<Api>(() => new Api('teams')) ;

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Or try to have a separate file for your service locator like:

**service_locator.dart**

```
GetIt sl = GetIt.instance;

final httpLink = HttpLink(...);

final GraphQLClient client = GraphQLClient(
  cache: InMemoryCache(),
  link: httpLink,
);

void setUpServiceLocator() {
  // Services
  sl.registerSingleton<LocationsService>(LocationsService(http.Client()));
  ...

  // Managers
  sl.registerSingleton<LocationsManager>(LocationsManager());
  ...
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setUpServiceLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**some_file.dart**

```
import 'package:my_awesome_app/service_locator.dart';

...
// call it anywhere you want on your code
sl<LocationsManager>().updateLocationsCommand.execute(query);

// or
sl.get<LocationsManager>().updateLocationsCommand.execute(query);
```

Comment: Still the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

It can be missing annotation on the class that you want to inject

```
@injectable
```

Answer (score 2):

answer for those who face this error in 2021 with
dependency get_it: ^5.0.3

> make class locator. dart

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:rest_api_work/Service/note_service.dart';

final locator = GetIt.instance;

void setUpLocator() 
{

locator.registerLazySingleton<NoteService>(() =>NoteService());

}
```

> Now call this method **setUpLocator** in main.dart

```
  void main() 
 {

   setUpLocator() ;
   runApp(MyApp());
  }
```

> and now make a property of locator class where you show your data because my data is list type you can see in noteservice.dart that's why I receive this property in the List type class

```
List<NoteForListing> notes = [];
 void initState()  {
         List<NoteForListing> service =  locator.get<NoteService>().getNotesList();
 
    setState(() {
      notes = service;    });
  
       super.initState();   }
```

> and at last noteserverice.dart

```
import 'package:rest_api_work/models/note_for_listing.dart';

class NoteService
{
  List<NoteForListing> getNotesList()
  {
     return
     [
    new NoteForListing(
      noteID :"1",
      noteTitle:"Note 1",
      createDateTime:DateTime.now(),
      latestEditDateTime:DateTime.now()
    ),
       new NoteForListing(
      noteID :"2",
      noteTitle:"Note 2",
      createDateTime:DateTime.now(),
      latestEditDateTime:DateTime.now()
    ),
       new NoteForListing(
      noteID :"3",
      noteTitle:"Note 3",
      createDateTime:DateTime.now(),
      latestEditDateTime:DateTime.now()
    )
  ];
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try version GetIt. I use ^3.0.3. It work for me. Maybe you use old version.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to run this command line:

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to fix the issue.
In terminal run:

1. **flutter clean**
2. **flutter pub get**

Answer (score -2):

try to use this:

```
GetIt.instance.registerSingleton<LocationsManager>(LocationsManager());
```

Comment: Your code does exactly the same thing as one of the examples in the earlier answer

Comment: There is no difference between this code snippet and that of the original post.

Answer (score -2):

I had this same issue today, and I solve it just adding the "object type" in the main file, just like this:

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  getIt.registerSingleton(ObjectType()); 
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```